# Linq to SQL group and count top 25

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, count

I have two tables in my database who looks like this:

User:

```
userid(int)
username(varchar)
```

Score:

```
scoreid(int)
result(bit)
attackinguserid(int) (same as User.userid)
```

They also contain other information but that's not important right now. What i want is to get the top 25 users who has score = true and display them like this:

```
Username: Won:
Peter     28
Mike      25
Kim       20
```

And so on...
The code I have been trying is this:

```
var winners = (from s in dc.Scores
                       from u in dc.Users
                       where (s.result) && (s.attackinguserid == u.userid)
                       group u by s
                       into groups
                       select new
                                  {
                                      Username= groups.Key,
                                      Won= groups.Count()
                                  }
                      ).OrderByDescending(x => x.Seire).Distinct().Take(25);

        gvBestPlayers.DataSource = winners; //gvBestPlayers = gridview
        gvBestPlayers.DataBind();
```

But this gives me error on the DataBind(). The error: NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code. The member 'System.Web.UI.Page.Title' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: Does the query work when you put the results in a `List<T>` instead of databinding it?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean @Aphelion or how to put the results in a list<T>.

Comment: That does not work @Aphelion. I get the same error.

Comment: Is it somehow possible that the query accesses the `System.Web.UI.Page.Title` property? The query tries to translate a part that it does not support as the error indicates. You need to find that part and exclude it from the query.

Comment: You don't have any idea what i can be? have been trying and failing with almost every part of the query now.

Comment: @Twister No i'm sorry. You could try to split the query in multiple parts then invoke them individually by using `ToList()`. You need to find the part that is using the `Page`.

Comment: @Aphelion i changed: group u by s, to group s by u, and it works, but it does not give med the username.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11627/discussion-between-aphelion-and-twistar)

Comment: Which line do you get the exception on when debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it my self. Here is the working code:

```
var winners = (from s in dc.Scores 
               from u in dc.Users 
               where (s.result) && (s.attackinguserid == u.userid) 
               group s by u 
               into groups 
               select new 
               { 
                   Username= groups.Key.username, 
                   Won= groups.Count() 
               }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Seire).Distinct().Take(25).ToList(); 

gvBestPlayers.DataSource = winners; 
gvBestPlayers.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var a = (from s in dc.Scores
                     join u in dc.Users on s.attackinguserid equals u.userid
                     let count = dc.Scores.Where(id => id.attackinguserid == u.userid ).Count()
                     where s.result == true
                     select new { Username = u.username, Won = count }).ToList().Distinct();
```